# iPhone phone number format NSFormatter

Tags: ios, formatting, phone-number, nsformatter

I'm copying phone number from iPhone address book to a text field. In text field it is showing as 1 (234) 567-8901. I want format it to 12345678901.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: withString:` to remove characters you don't want such as `@"("` with `@""`

EDIT: Better solution.

```
NSCharacterSet *charSet =[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()- "];
cleanedPhoneNumber = [phoneNumberString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charSet];
```